# Python requests with stream=True is unable to iterate through content depending on the machine

Tags: python, http, get, stream, python-requests

So, I'm using the following snippet of code to fetch parts of a web page and parse it (not related to this problem).

```
def load_max_resp(self, resp, size=4096):
    it = resp.iter_content()
    file_str = StringIO()
    for i in xrange(size):
        try:
            file_str.write(it.next())
        except StopIteration:
            break
    return file_str.getvalue()
```

the resp element is loaded with: 
`resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)`

This fragment of code works properly on my own machine/network, I have no problem whatsoever. When I upload it to my server, however, sometimes the `iter_content()` returns an empty iterator (when I call `it.next()` for the first time it throws as `StopIteration` exception). This only happens on some (most, actually) website, always the same.

I have tested it in a console/interpreter and if I remove the `stream=True` parameter it works as intended but I cannot remove it because I need to only download a max amount of bytes from the page (to avoid network congestion). I have upgraded to the latest requests package from pip and I made sure the library is the same on my development and production machine.

My wild guess is that there's an Linux flag somewhere stopping some streamed connection? (Using ubuntu on dev machine, Debian wheezy on production server).

Alternatively, how do I make an HTTP request (a GET) specifying a maximum allowed return value for the resource? I cannot test the headers because some websites don't have a content-length.

Answer (score 0):

> Alternatively, how do I make an HTTP request (a GET) specifying a
>   maximum allowed return value for the resource? I cannot test the
>   headers because some websites don't have a content-length.

You might want to look at [Byte serving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving)

> *Byte serving* is the process of sending only a portion of an HTTP/1.1
>   message from a server to a client. Byte serving uses the `Range` HTTP
>   request header and the `Accept-Ranges` and `Content-Range` HTTP response
>   headers.